# How to do join pandas dataframes based on multiple columns?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, join

I have 2 dataframes like below:

```
level                        title
Level 0                      Effective
Level 1                      Evaluation
Level 1                      Ice Breaker
Level 1                      Fire
Level 2                      Introduction
Level 2                      Understanding
Level 3                      Connect
```

and

```
level                        title
Level 0                      Effective
Level 1                      Evaluation
Level 1                      Comedy
Level 2                      Introduction
Level 2                      Understanding
Level 4                      Connect
```

I want to join them based on both columns, matching entries should be in front of each other while missing entries should have `Null` in them. The required output would be like this:

```
level               title               level               title
Level 0             Effective           Level 0             Effective
Level 1             Evaluation          Level 1             Evaluation
Level 1             Ice Breaker 
                                        Level 1             Comedy
Level 1             Fire    
Level 2             Introduction        Level 2             Introduction
Level 2             Understanding       Level 2             Understanding
Level 3             Connect             
                                        Level 4             Connect
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) but first differentiate the column names on the left/right (e.g. with [`add_suffix`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.add_suffix.html)):

```
out = df1.merge(df2.add_suffix('_'), how='outer',
                left_on=['level', 'title'],
                right_on=['level_', 'title_'])
```

Output:

```
     level          title   level_         title_
0  Level 0      Effective  Level 0      Effective
1  Level 1     Evaluation  Level 1     Evaluation
2  Level 1    Ice Breaker      NaN            NaN
3  Level 1           Fire      NaN            NaN
4  Level 2   Introduction  Level 2   Introduction
5  Level 2  Understanding  Level 2  Understanding
6  Level 3        Connect      NaN            NaN
7      NaN            NaN  Level 1         Comedy
8      NaN            NaN  Level 4        Connect
```

Another approach if you want to be able to sort on the merged keys:

```
out = (df1.merge(df2, how='outer',
                 left_on=[df1['level'], df1['title']],
                 right_on=['level', 'title'])
          .sort_values(by=['level'])
          #.drop(columns=['level', 'title']) # uncomment to drop merged keys
      )
```

Output:

```
     level          title  level_x        title_x  level_y        title_y
0  Level 0      Effective  Level 0      Effective  Level 0      Effective
1  Level 1     Evaluation  Level 1     Evaluation  Level 1     Evaluation
2  Level 1    Ice Breaker  Level 1    Ice Breaker      NaN            NaN
3  Level 1           Fire  Level 1           Fire      NaN            NaN
7  Level 1         Comedy      NaN            NaN  Level 1         Comedy
4  Level 2   Introduction  Level 2   Introduction  Level 2   Introduction
5  Level 2  Understanding  Level 2  Understanding  Level 2  Understanding
6  Level 3        Connect  Level 3        Connect      NaN            NaN
8  Level 4        Connect      NaN            NaN  Level 4        Connect
```

Comment: How can I make it so that the the levels are sorted regardless of whether their corresponding entry exists or not? That is the level 1 comedy should be after level 1 fire.

Comment: @Labeeb I don't see a logic for that. You could sort by level, then title, but how comedy should be in between Ice breaker and Fire doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: Nevertheless, I added another approach that gives you an intermediate column with merged keys, which might help you to achieve a custom sorting. If this doesn't work, please open a new question.